# highchart tooltip hover - on busy charts the tooltip jumps between the points

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, mousehover

Im using high-chart of type 'area' and SVG tooltip. On a chart with a lot of points, when i hover the tooltip area and i move my mouse on the tooltip it jumps to other closest point tooltip. is there a way to open the tooltip only when i hover on the exact point? (don't want to be forced to click on a point to get tooltip)

i tried stickyTracking false/true, snap, hide delay

i expect the tooltip on hover to stay on tooltip area unless i move the mouse directly to other point

Answer (score 0):

You can set `findNearestPointBy` property to `'xy'`:

```
series: [{
    type: 'area',
    findNearestPointBy: 'xy',
    data: [...]
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4pzd8L2b/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.findNearestPointBy

Comment: Thanks but it didnt solve my problem. 
see the example below - when you have a long tooltip and you move your mouse while hovering, it will jump to the point next to it.. 
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        findNearestPointBy: 'xy',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,]
    }],
    tooltip: {
    shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
        return 'very long title. move the mouse to your right and see it jump to second point'
        }
    }
});

Comment: Hi @Ravit, Ok, I see the problem. Please check if the result with `stickyTracking` fills your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s48yrkq2/ ?